# I want to get an alert if email already exits in my database in c# with help of execute scalar method

Tags: c#

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string db = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + "-" + DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value + "-" + DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=BAN095\\SQLEXPRESS; database=Reg-DB; integrated security=SSPI");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select EmailID from Reg where EmailID='" + txtEmail.Text + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        Int32 count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (count==0)
        {
            Response.Write("email already Exists");
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Reg(FirstName,LastName,EmailID,PhoneNum,Gender,DOB)values('" + txtFirstName.Text + "','" + txtLastName.Text + "','" + txtEmail.Text + "','" + txtMobile.Text + "','" + RdoGender.SelectedItem.Value + "','" + db + "')";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Please help me with this. And also for errors like  *use new keyword to create an object instance* that I’m getting.

Comment: you get error in which line?

Comment: What if mail ID is `'; DROP TABLE Reg;--`?

Comment: Not related to your error, but yous should use parametrized queries. The code is vulnerable to sql injection obviuosly.

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` is supposed to return an `EmailID`.How can you cast it to `Int32`?

Comment: @sindhu for your awareness don't share any sensitive information in stack overflow like  data source and server name. use datasource: XXXX  users will understand.

Comment: create new instance in else part. cmd = new SqlCommand(" insert into reg(...").

Answer (score 0):

Put a unique index on EmailID, then perform just the insert and catch for `SqlException`s and check if `exception.Number == 2601`

Note: Use `using` statements to ensure that `IDisposable`s will be disposed and use parameterized commands!

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string db = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + "-" + DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value + "-" + DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value;
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=BAN095\\SQLEXPRESS; database=Reg-DB; integrated security=SSPI"))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Reg(FirstName,LastName,EmailID,PhoneNum,Gender,DOB)values(@FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@Mobile,@Gender,@Db)", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
            //Do the same with other parameters
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Number == 2601) // If instead of unique index, you have a unique constraint/primary key, check for ex.number==2627
                {
                    // Duplicate key! Do whatever you want
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: or a `Select count(*)` may be.